# I can't pose my character with the hair particle system

Tags: particles

I've made a tiger and a hair particle system for fur. It all worked well until I rigged it. The model moved with the bones bit not the hair. Please help[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your modifier stack. You most likely have the Armature under the particle system (usually happens when creating something like this). Instead, you will want the armature to be above the particle system so that the hair grows out of the deformed model.